# importing a class in java

Tags: java, class, import

Should I import a java class if the class I am importing is in the same package as the class I am importing to (I'm trying to extend the former class, both savingsAccount and SpecialSavings are in the same account)? Also I'm trying to access a private variable in my parent class from the sub-class but it won't let me. Here is my code:

```
package finance;

import finance.SavingsAccount;

public class SpecialSavings extends SavingsAccount
{

    public SpecialSavings(double savingsBalance) 
    {
        super.setBalance(savingsBalance);
    }

    if (super.getBalance() > 10000)
    {
        modifyInterestRate(10);
    }

}
```

Here is the code for SavingsAccount:

```
 package finance;

 public class SavingsAccount 
 {
private static double annualInterestRate;
private double savingsBalance;//indicates the amount the saver currently has on deposit

public SavingsAccount(double savingsBalance)//default constructor
{
    this.savingsBalance = savingsBalance;
}


public double calculateMonthlyInterest() 
{
    savingsBalance += savingsBalance * ((annualInterestRate/100)/12);
    return savingsBalance;
}

public static void modifyInterestRate(double newValue)
{
    annualInterestRate = newValue;
}
/*-------------getters and setters------------------------*/
public void setBalance(double newValue)
{
    savingsBalance = newValue;
}

public double getBalance()
{
    return savingsBalance;
}



 }
```

Comment: show the code for `SavingsAccount`, also is this `homework` if so add it as a tag.

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't need to import classes from the same package.
2. You cannot access private variable of a class from a different class ( unless it is an inner class) If you want to let a variable be visible to subclasses, use `protected`, not `private`.

Also, you are trying to call `super.getBalance()` outside of any block, which is illegal, you should move it into some method of yours. For **example**:

```
public void modify()
{
    if (super.getBalance() > 10000)
    {
        modifyInterestRate(10);
    }
}
```

Comment: im using getters which are public? can you not do that?

Comment: You can do it with getters, but not directly. if `x` is a private member of `someclass`, then - `someclass.getX()` is OK. `someclass.x` is not.

Comment: the spec im following already made the parent classes method private so I can not modify it. so i am using getters and setters as you can see in the above code

Comment: ok so eclipse is giveing me this error message. "Implicit super constructor SavingsAccount() is undefined. Must explicitly invoke another constructor"

Comment: This is a different problem. And instead of writing that in comment - read this: http://www.particle.kth.se/~lindsey/JavaCourse/Book/Part1/Java/Chapter04/thisSuperConstr.html

Answer (score 0):

No. All classes within your namespace are visible and usable without explicitly importing them.

Answer (score 0):

To access `super class` variables make the `protected`, but a better solution is to make `protected setter/getters` for that `private` instance variable and use them instead.

Answer (score 0):

There are `3 access modifier`

1. Private
2. Protected
3. Public

And `4 access control`

1. Private
2. Default
3. Protected
   4  Public

As you are in the **same package, there is NO NEED TO IMPORT**.

And as you want to access the **Parent class private member** from its subclass, that **illegal**.
If that **subclass is in the same package you can make the member of the Parent class which you want to access as Default** (ie not writing any access modifier), or **if the subclass is outside the Parent package, then use the protected or public.**